# Excel: Order by date within multiple IDs

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a huge epidemiological dataset containing registry data with pathology reports and clinical information. I have merged several files into one masterfile in order to get all information from one file. Every patient is assigned an unique ID-number. Each patient can have several reports and hence the same ID number can be repeated several times in the ID column. For each ID entry = new row (= pathology or clinical report) there is a date of that sample/information reported.

My goal is to be able to read all pathology/clinical info for a particular ID within one row.[image]

By sorting the IDs, I get a clear picture of the number of each ID that has been entered. The problem  arises when there are several reports = multiple rows with identical ID because the dates within this one patients with several IDs = rows do not match. The dates come from pathology (sample date, answer date, clinical info date etc). The dates from pathology and clinical within one patient does not have to match exactly on the day but still within a reasonable timeframe e.g. within 1-2 months. This is best illustrated with an example.

I want to sort the columns so that dates from a particular row match together. I am sure there is a way to do that but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Before you sort by ID, do the rows appear to line up correctly?

Comment: Nope, mismatch as well. So I want to sort by date and by multiple "date columns" for each one unique ID with several rows. I have around 30k unique IDs and about 130k rows (= same ID can be repeated)

Comment: Since you merged together multiple tables, are the original tables sorted in any way?

Comment: Thx for the question. I went back to the original files but could not find any particular pattern of order. The unique IDs with multiple rows are together but even there the dates are not chronological (within the same IDs). So, I cannot just sort by date in any of the original files because than I would lose track of IDs with multiple rows.

Comment: What am I missing?  Your second table looks like it can be produced from the first by sorting on ID, and Date, in that order.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The records aren't properly lining up once merged. Date pathology and pathology report are correctly lined up, and date clinical and clinical report are correctly lined up, however pathology and clinical are not lined up. Cancer1 should match TreatmentA, Cancer2 to TreatmentB and so on.

Comment: Make two copies of the table, remove the clincal columns from one and the pathology columns from the other, then sort both tables on Id then Date, then put the two tables together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue of mismatching records seems to arise once the two separate tables are merged into one. In order to fix this, there are several options you can take:

1. Re-do the merge but strengthen the way in which the tables are joined on.

   - Instead of only merging based on `ID`, see if there is another field that could easily connect the records, perhaps a `medical record #`, `case #`, or `event #`, and merge the tables based on this new field AND `ID`. This would be the strongest solution, however it will only work if you can find said field to strengthen the link.
2. A separate solution would be to first sort the original tables based on the dates so that they match up and then re-merging them together.

   - In theory this should solve your problem as I assume currently when matching up the two separate tables it is grabbing the first instance of patient X01 from both tables and matching them together. This can be confirmed by checking the merged query and looking to see if the mismatched records are in the same order as presented in the original tables. This is not perfect, as it relies on no clinical dates occurring  between pathology dates for the record, so I would proceed with caution.
   - And to address your concern about losing track of ID's with multiple rows, this should not matter as in the end result after merged you can then sort by ID, however you can add multiple levels of sort by selecting the data and going to **Data** -> `Sort` -> `Add Level`. You can change the order in which the data is sorted (*First by `ID` and then by `Date`*).

Comment: Hi Steven! You were right! I re-ordered the individual files by ID and then added date level and then merged everything into one masterfile. That did the trick. Data looks ready now, did some random probes and alignment is perfect. Thank you again for taking the time, really appreciate! Wish you all the best! Ilja